# Trying to test some url addresses is working or not with python request but getting errors

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-codes

I'm trying to learn the test some internet addresses with python request and expecting some outputs (like 200 or 404). But i get errors which i couldn't figured out. I'm also open to any advice for my purpose.

```
import os , sys , requests
from multiprocessing import Pool

def url_check(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    print(resp.status_code)

with Pool(4) as p:
    print(p.map(url_check, [ "https://api.github.com​", "​http://bilgisayar.mu.edu.tr/​", "​https://www.python.org/​", "http://akrepnalan.com/ceng2034​", "https://github.com/caesarsalad/wow​" ]))
```

Output of the code with errors:

```
404
404
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "ödev_deneme.py", line 6, in url_check
    resp = requests.get(url)
  File "/home/efe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/efe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/efe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/efe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 637, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "/home/efe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 728, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '\u200bhttps://www.python.org/\u200b'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ödev_deneme.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(p.map(url_check, [ "https://api.github.com​", "​http://bilgisayar.mu.edu.tr/​", "​https://www.python.org/​", "http://akrepnalan.com/ceng2034​", "https://github.com/caesarsalad/wow​" ]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '\u200bhttps://www.python.org/\u200b'
```

My expecting output must be like this:

```
200
200
200
404
200
```

There is 404 on Fourth line because forth url address is not working. But in my output there are already 404 in first two line. There is a huge mistake in my code i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that some of the urls include invisible ZERO WIDTH SPACE characters (`'\u200b'`).

You can replace them with an empty string:

```
def url_check(url):
    resp = requests.get(url.replace('\u200b', ''))
    print(resp.status_code)
```